# Python Tkinter stdout redirect of child process not printing to GUI widget (Assistance Needed)

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing

Currently I'm running Python 3.5.

My file basically has two GUI windows...the first asks for input, and after submitting that input, the second appears while a function executes.  During this time, this function is ran in a separate thread from the GUI.

Additionally, the thread calls a function with multiprocessing.pool command which calls another function to perform the same task multiple times.

Unfortunately, all the stdout output is sent to the console and not the Text Widget of my second GUI (The first GUI works as I utilize a stdout redirector class).  I have tried two different versions of my code to try and solve this issue...one was to put my functions internal to the GUI, and another keep them outside.

When putting them internal to the GUI, the redirector works...but then the processes doesn't run multiple instances, just one at a time (which I'm assuming is due to only utilizing one thread, unsure).

When keeping the functions outside multiple processes are ran, and everything works, but the output from the child processes that are being ran (as stated before, they just output to the console).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the pertinent code:

```
class StdoutRedirector(object):
  def __init__(self,text_widget):
    self.text_space = text_widget
  def write(self,string):
    self.text_space.insert('end', string)
    self.text_space.see('end')
  def flush(self):
    pass

class OutputWindowGUI:
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    root.wm_title("GUI")
    self.label = Label(root, text="Output:", font=24).grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
    self.root.geometry("650x600")
    self.root.lift()
    self.root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    self.root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',False)

    self.textBoxFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    self.textBoxFrame.grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky=E+W)

    self.textbox=Text(self.textBoxFrame)
    self.textbox=Text(wrap=WORD)
    self.textbox.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=W, pady=2)


    sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector(self.textbox)
    sys.stdin = StdoutRedirector(self.textbox)
    sys.stderr = StdoutRedirector(self.textbox)

    self.buttonFrameClose = tkinter.Frame(root)
    self.buttonFrameClose.grid(row=6, column=3)
    self.buttonFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    self.buttonFrame.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=3)
    self.close_all_button = Button(self.buttonFrameClose, text='Close App', command=self.close_all, height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

    self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target = apply_async_with_callback)
    self.gui_thread.start()


  def close_all(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    sys.exit(1)



def start_commands(a_device, vpntermination):
  time.sleep(.1)
  try:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
    hostname = net_connect.send_command("show hostname") #Used to store Hostname.
    output = net_connect.send_command("vpn-sessiondb logoff name " + str(vpntermination) +  " noconfirm") #Used for vpn termination command.
    print('\n******* Output for device ' + hostname + ' *******' )
    print(output)
    print('')
    net_connect.disconnect() 
  except (NetMikoTimeoutException, NetMikoAuthenticationException) as e: #Handles timeout errors.
    print("Could not connect to " + a_device.get("ip") + ", Error: ", e)
    print('')

def apply_async_with_callback():
  start_time = datetime.now()

  with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    results = [pool.apply_async(start_commands, args = (a_device, vpntermination)) for a_device in all_firewalls]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

  end_time = datetime.now() 
  total_time = end_time - start_time 
  print('\nTotal process time: ' + str(total_time))

def main():
  credentials()

  master = Tk()
  my_gui = InputWindowGUI(master)
  master.mainloop()

  root=Tk()
  out_gui = OutputWindowGUI(root)
  root.mainloop() 

if __name__=='__main__':
  freeze_support()
  main()
```

Comment: You cannot have two instances of `Tk`. There may be other problems, but that's definitely the first one. You also can't reliably call methods on a widget from any thread other than the one that created the widget, so that's likely a second problem.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit on the two instances of TK...the first is destroyed upon submitting the Input...then the second is instantiated.

Comment: That explains why the stdout redirect works when I put the functions within the GUI...can you elaborate on why possibly my processes don't perform multiprocessing when inside the GUI class?

Comment: I see. I didn't look closely enough. Though, I fail to see what advantage there is in immediately creating a window after the first one is destroyed. Tkinter _can_ work that way, but it's not how it was designed to work. Why not just create an instance of `Toplevel` for the second window?

Comment: Yes, I could do that too...which makes sense.  But the largest issue I'm facing now is my multiprocessing won't work within the GUI while processing it through the child processes...basically I call the thread so the function runs on the side so it doesn't freeze my GUI, but it only iterates through one process at a time instead of utilizing the 3 processes I set for the Pool.